Whole class summoned to another world, students paired together to fight monsters
It's a manwha / manga / manhua where the whole class is summoned to another world. The students get paired together (1 boy & 1 girl) and force to have (Special event) [Sex?] which becomes a chain to control the male student who are forced to fight monsters.
It is in black and white.
The male lead looks like a samurai and uses a sword, the female lead, who has black hair, wears glasses and a maid outfit.
What is the name of this? Anyone have any ideas?

This all sounds charming and not at all pervy and weird

You owe me a new sarcasm detector - it just blew up…

@JonCuster - The very sad part is that I think I might have read some of this while looking for another answer a few years ago. I seem to recall he wakes up in a white dungeon. I noped out when I realised that it was a BDSM porno.

yep, its answered in this :
Isekai manga where the main character has the power to cut anything he believes he can cut
I Was Summoned to Another World, but I Got the Power to Cut Anything, so It Was Easy Mode?
